# Can't make another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

[I want another new activity in my project but i can not make it. I don't know what is the problem but the java activity shows red. Please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AqwV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having an issue somewhere in your XML-files which cause an error and so the R.layout-files can not be compiled. This is the reason why your activity_main2-Layout is in red. Unfortunately Android Studio does not highlight the file with the root error.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate cache and restart the android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Place your cursor at the red labeled text. A dialog will prompt with more details about the error. Could you show us that error?

Also. It would be helpful if you paste the whole code of the Main2Activity, not a screenshot please.